# How to remove the Root node from xml while converting to json using xslt

Tags: json, xml, xslt-2.0, root

{"Root": {
    "u_effective_date": "2017-03-27",
    "u_name": "Test",
    "u_preferred_name": "Test",
    "u_title": "Dir Human Resources",
    "u_department": "Human Resources"
}}

to

Required output:
{
    "u_effective_date": "2017-03-27",
    "u_name": "Test",
    "u_preferred_name": "Test",
    "u_title": "Dir Human Resources",
    "u_department": "Human Resources"
}

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"
xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync">
<u_effective_date>2017-03-27</u_effective_date>
<u_name>Test</u_name>
<u_preferred_name>Test</u_preferred_name>
<u_title>Dir Human Resources</u_title>
<u_department>Human Resources</u_department>
</Root>
```

Below is the xslt i am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">{
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>}
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object or Element Property-->
<xsl:template match="*">
    "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Array Element -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object Properties -->
<xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>



        <xsl:otherwise>{

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            }</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Attribute Property -->
<xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: XSLT transforms XML not JSON. Use any general purpose language (Java, PHP, Python, etc.) to read in JSON and re-map the dictionary/list items.

Comment: Below is the xml i am trying to convert into Json format
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"
    xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ws="urn:com.workday/workersync">
    <u_effective_date>2017-03-27</u_effective_date>
    <u_name>Test</u_name>
    <u_preferred_name>Test</u_preferred_name>
    <u_title>Dir Human Resources</u_title>
    <u_department>Human Resources</u_department> 
</Root>

Comment: Hi Parfait, thanks for your reply.. I have updated the question with the xml and xslt..what should i edit to skip the root node in the xml and output from the child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the top level template match from `"/"` to `"/Root"`. That's it!

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Root">{
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
}
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object or Element Property-->
<xsl:template match="*">
    "<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Array Element -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
    <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Object Properties -->
<xsl:template name="Properties">
    <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name(*[1])"/>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1">{ "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] }</xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>{    
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        }</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Attribute Property -->
<xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
{

    "u_effective_date" : "2017-03-27",
    "u_name" : "Test",
    "u_preferred_name" : "Test",
    "u_title" : "Dir Human Resources",
    "u_department" : "Human Resources"
}
```